# What is the best word processor to use with Elementary OS?

Tags: applications

I am still deciding which Linux distro to download on my new laptop. One of the things I do on the laptop is writing. Is there a good but free word processor to use with this OS?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's an opinion based question so you're so to get a lot of different responses. I personally us LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 1):

I used Softmaker FreeOffice for quite some time, but it was quite laggy when backspacing a lot of text, typing and doing very basic tasks, really. And I have a powerful hardware, so it was not my fault.

I then moved to OnlyOffice, quite good even if not perfect: it does not integrate well with the rest of the OS and had a bare bone selection of fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I can use any office application like MS Office, LibreOffice, Google Suite and other.
But favourite is LibreOffice  Writer, Google Doc and Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am a writer and I prefer WPS Office: [Homepage](https://www.wps.com)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use microsoft office 2007 on crossover linux or wps office 2016